# Using Hashes as Unique ID

Tags: database-design

I am creating a database that will hold a number of transaction records.

I was wondering if it is a good idea or good practice to use a hash function that can be replicated easily for verification as the ID column. i.e. SHA1(UserID + TimeOfTransaction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally not a good idea, for the following reasons:

- If someone knows `UserID` and times, they may be able to match that back to transactions (depending on how this ID is exposed - if it's exposed externally via an API, someone knowing `UserID` could generate candidate `TransactionIDs` from guessed times)
- High amount of entropy in the key means that your indexes on this key are going to fragment rapidly. If your DB has a page cache, the cache efficiency will drop as your data volume grows (this can be a killer).
- If you can handle the performance concerns, then why not just generate a GUID?

Comment: The performance is going to be a major concern, but I would also like an identifier that customers can see that isn't just a simple number that can be guessed. If they have an issue then the support can ask for it. Would it be best to keep the number ID and have a separate randomly generated UID.

Comment: By all means use a UID as an alternate key, but don't use it as the PK or in FKs (ie: don't join to other tables using it). If your database has the concept of clustered indexes, do not cluster on it.

Comment: obligatory fun read: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/the-automated-curse-generator

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to use a hash as the ID, especially if you are making the ID the Primary Key and will have tables Foreign Keyed to this table. An SHA1 hash is 20 bytes and cannot be decoded (i.e. you cannot derive the source values from it). It would be better (generally, the RDBMS being used hasn't been specified) for indexing if the values were sequential, and it would be better for JOINs if the values were narrower.

What you should do is use a surrogate key (auto-incrementing) as the ID / PK and then a separate field, something non-sequential, as what you give out to customers. This separate field, which should be indexed as well, is known as an "alternate key".

Fortunately, you can accomplish your goals of having "an identifier that customers can see that isn't just a simple number that can be guessed", and not degrading performance *and* be able to decode the value back into its souce value, all in just 4 bytes (i.e. an `INT`). You accomplish this by using Modular Multiplicative Inverses. To learn more about this concept, please see the following two Stack Overflow questions I have answered using this method

[Generating a random, non-repeating sequence of all integers in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102073/generating-a-random-non-repeating-sequence-of-all-integers-in-net/35103941#35103941)

[Generate different random time in the given interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314054/generate-different-random-time-in-the-given-interval/27826049#27826049)

Interesting / good timing for this questions as I just gave a short presentation on this very topic last night. I don't have the slides and testing code published yet, but I have posted on PasteBin the script that creates the objects: [T-SQL script to create Multiplicative Inverse objects](http://pastebin.com/vuK1Aiiv).

In order to use the functions in that script, you would:

1. Pick an upper limit for how many numbers you could possibly generate that need to be unique. Going over this limit would begin to repeat values. This value is the "Modulo".
2. Pick a "Base" value that, when you run `MMI.ModularMultiplicativeInverse`, you get a value back that is not `-1`. The result of this function will be the Multiplicative Inverse.

   ```
   SELECT MMI.ModularMultiplicativeInverse(17000903, 10000000);
   ```

   Returns:

   ```
   4696567
   ```
3. Write down the initial 2 values used to generate the MMI, and the MMI itself.
4. Pass those values into `MMI.GenerateTest` to see if the pattern (i.e. the variation in the far right field: `DifferenceFromPrior`) is good enough. If there is too little variation, go back to Step 2 and try another "Base" value.

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM MMI.GenerateTest(17000903, 10000000, 4696567, 60000);
   ```
5. To get the pseudo-random values, call the `Encode` function:

   ```
   SELECT MMI.Encode(17000903, 10000000, 5); -- 5004515
   ```
6. To get the source values, call the `Decode` function:

   ```
   SELECT MMI.Decode(4696567, 10000000, 5004515); -- 5
   ```